# undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pyqt5, qthread

I'm new with PyQt. But that is showing an error. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.How can I solve this problem?
Here is the error:

> QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
> /bin/python3: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("My First PyQt Application")
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You get that error just by *running* a script with the above code?

Comment: Are you using VSCode?

Comment: This is not a PyQt problem. If you run the script in a normal terminal (i.e. not VSCode), it will work as expected.